# Prove that any affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to the standard topology.

Tags: general-topology

Consider the topological space $R^n$ with the standard topology. Let $A$ be any affine subspace. Prove that $A$ is a closed subset of $R^n$.

If I recall things correctly then an affine subspace is a subspace of the form
\begin{align*}
A=\{\vec{x}\in X|\vec{x}=\vec{u}+\vec{v}\}
\end{align*}
where $\vec{u}$ is a fixed vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\vec{v}\in V$ for some subspace $V$.

I should also be able to equivalently say the following.
\begin{align*}
A=\{\vec{x}\in X|\vec{x}-\vec{u}\in V\}.
\end{align*}

I'm really not sure how to tackle this problem. My main tools available at the moment are properties of Hausdorff spaces and properties of continuous functions between topological spaces. I would really like to make a continuous function from $A$ to some space where the image of $A$ under $f$ is closed but so far I haven't gotten anywhere. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's often the case that the easiest way to show that a subset is closed is to show that its complement is open.  I suggest that approach here, using the fact that if $\vec{x} \notin V$, then it has some positive distance from $V$.

Comment: Possibly. One issue I see immediately is that $V$ is not a particular vector. So we can say that $\vec{x}$ has some positive distance from any vector in $V$ but it doesn't really make sense to talk about a vectors distance from a set. If I could show that this collection of distances had a non-zero minimum then I could possibly make an open ball argument for openness using the metric.

Comment: You can, in fact, make exactly that argument in $\Bbb R^n$.  (It's not necessarily true in an infinite-dimensional vector space.)

Comment: Robert Shore, as I said for another post, it's probably better to avoid invoking the inner product structure, since this argument can be made in the context of abstract topological vector spaces.

Comment: Given this disagreement (and we're both making valid points) the OP should clarify what propositions he or she is free to use.

Comment: I believe that I have provided a valid solution below.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:

> If $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $V$ is closed.

As $\mathbb{R}^n$ is finite dimensional, any subspace is complemented. In other words, $V=S^\perp$ for some subspace $S$, namely $S=V^\perp$. Note that

$$
V=\{v\in \mathbb{R}^n: \forall w\in S (w\cdot v=0)\}=\bigcap_{w\in S}\{v\in\mathbb{R}^n:w\cdot v=0\}
$$
which is an intersection of closed sets, because the map $v\mapsto w\cdot v$ is continuous.

Step 2:

For any fixed $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the map $v\mapsto v+u$ is a homeomorphism  of $\mathbb{R}^n$, thus sends closed sets to closed sets.

EDIT:

Here's another approach:

Let $v_1,\dots,v_k$ be a basis of $V$. Extend to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as $v_1,\dots,v_n$. Consider the dual basis $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n$, which is to say 
$$
\phi_i\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jv_j\right)=\lambda_i
$$
i.e. $\phi_i$ maps each vector to the $i$th coefficient appearing in the expression of that vector as a linear combination of $v_1,\dots,v_n$. Note that
$$
v=\sum_{i=1}^n \phi_i(v)v_i
$$
for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Each $\phi_i$ is continuous (can be established by hand, or by invoking the fact that the space has finite dimension), so $\ker(\phi_i)$ is closed for every $i$. But
$$
V=\bigcap_{i=1}^k\ker(\phi_i)
$$

Yet another approach: use that a sequence $\langle w_l:l\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$ converges to $w$ if and only if, for each $i$, $\phi_i(w_l)$ converges to $\phi_i(w)$ as $l\to\infty$. This can be used to check that any subspace is sequentially closed.

Comment: How is $V$ an intersection of closed sets. I am also unfamiliar with what you mean by a complemented subspace. Some elaboration here would be helpful.

Comment: @Walt I added some clarification. Does that work?

Comment: OP might not be able to use that subspace have compliments, and this doesnt seem like a necessary tool.  You can directly prove subspace are closed by fixing a basis.  One can then decompose any convergent sequence into its representation w.r.t. the basis, and directly construct the limit as a linear combination of basis vectors.

Comment: @JakeMirra That's definitely doable, but it is a bit verbose, and you need to mention that the coordinate functionals are continuous, which again depends on the finite dimension. I do think that inner products are usually encountered before topology.

Comment: In fact, given the OP seems to be getting an introduction to topology and/or abstract vector spaces, I do think it's in the spirit of the problem to not use inner product structure.

Comment: @JakeMirra I have added a few different approaches

Answer (score 2):

In your post, you are looking for a function to use to conclude. Here is a sketch of an approach: it is enough to show that subspaces are closed, because affine spaces are translations of these, and the function $\vec x\mapsto \vec x+\vec u$ for fixed $\vec u$ is clearly a homeomorphism. So, let $V=\text{span}\ \{\vec v_2,\cdots,\vec v_k\};\ k\le n$, without loss of generality the $\vec v_i$ are independent. For arbitrary scalars $\alpha_i,$ define the map $\sum^k_{i=1}\alpha_i\vec v_i\mapsto (\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k)$, and show that it is a homeomorphism of $V$ onto the complete vector space $\mathbb R^k$.

Comment: Upvoted, as it proceeds as directly from definitions as possible and does not assume inner product structure.

Comment: How does the fact that that map is a homeomorphism onto $\mathbb{R}^k$ help?  Two metric spaces can be homeomorphic with one being complete and the other not being complete.

Answer (score 0):

First suppose $V$ has dimension $n-1$. If $w$ is a vector orthogonal to $V$, then the map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=(x-u)\cdot w$ is continuous. Since $A=f^{-1}(\{0\})$, it is closed. Induction on the codimension of $V$ then gives the general result, since a closed subset of a closed subset is closed.

Comment: Invoking the inner product seems like over kill for this problem, given the OP is working at the level of abstraction of vector spaces and topological spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Take $\{v_1,...,v_p\}$ to be a basis of $V$. We can extend this to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ denoted $\{v_1,...,v_p,v_{p+1},...,v_n\}$. For a vector $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we can write this as components relative to the chosen basis. Write this component vector as $\vec{x}=[x_1,...,x_n]$. Now define a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ as
\begin{align*}
f([x_1,...,x_n])=[x_1,...,x_p,0,...,0].
\end{align*}
Observe that each component function of $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$. In particular each component function is continuous. Therefore $f$ is continuous itself.

Now consider the fixed point set
\begin{align*}
Fix(f)=\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n|f(\vec{x})=\vec{x}\}.
\end{align*}
This fixed point set must be $V$. It Since $f$ we have that $f$ is continuous and $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff it follows that $V=Fix(f)$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ as desired.

Comment: Looks pretty good, Walt, but you have to mention that the mapping from $ x \in V $ to its coordinate representation $ rep(x) $ in $ R^n $ is a homeomorphism.